# Segmentation fault c++ causing program to crash

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run the following code but it crashes as soon as the object of inherited class is created.

The program works fine until the creation of the inherited class object but segmentation fault occurs after "Student *s" line is executed.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
protected:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
public:
    Person(string firstName, string lastName, int identification)
    {
        this->firstName = firstName;
        this->lastName = lastName;
        this->id = identification;
    }
    void printPerson()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << lastName << ", " << firstName << "\nID: " << id
                << "\n";
    }

};

class Student: public Person
{
private:
    vector<int> testScores;
public:
    Student(string f, string l, int i, vector<int>& scores) :
            Person(firstName, lastName, id)
    {
        this->firstName = f;
        this->lastName = l;
        this->id = i;
        this->testScores = scores;
    }

    char calculate()
    {
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        int sum = 0;
        for (it = testScores.begin(); it != testScores.end(); it++)
        {
            sum += *it;
        }
        int avg = sum / (testScores.size());
        if (avg >= 90 && avg <= 100)
            return 'O';
        else if (avg >= 80 && avg < 90)
            return 'E';
        else if (avg >= 70 && avg < 80)
            return 'A';
        else if (avg >= 55 && avg < 70)
            return 'P';
        else if (avg >= 40 && avg < 55)
            return 'D';
        else
            return 'T';

    }
};

int main()
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    int id;
    int numScores;
    cin >> firstName >> lastName >> id >> numScores;
    vector<int> scores;
    for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++)
    {
        int tmpScore;
        cin >> tmpScore;
        scores.push_back(tmpScore);
    }
    cout << "Calling\n";
    Student* s = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, scores);
    cout << "Done\n";
    s->printPerson();
    cout << "Grade: " << s->calculate() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i don't get the `Student(string f, string l, int i, vector<int>& scores) : Person(firstName, lastName, id)` statement. What are you trying to achieve by sending the uninitialized data members to the base class constructor?

Comment: `Student* s = new Student(firstName, lastName, id, scores);` does not seem to require dynamic allocation and there is no matching `delete` to release the `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Student(string f, string l, int i, vector<int>& scores) :
            Person(firstName, lastName, id)
```

uses `Person`'s own `firstName`, `lastName`, and `id` members to construct `Person`. This may or may not segfault and go boom, but is definitely going into undefined behaviour.

OP wants something more like this where the passed parameters are used instead:

```
    Student(string f, string l, int i, vector<int>& scores) :
            Person(f, l, i)
    {
        // all of the members that were set here don't need to be set. 
        // Person did it already
        this->testScores = scores;
    }
```

One more improvement can be made. `testScores` can be initialized with [the member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). This allows `scores` to be stuffed into `testScores` immediately and the compiler can make all sorts of interesting optimizations.

```
    Student(string f, string l, int i, vector<int>& scores) :
            Person(f, l, i), testScores(scores)
    {
    }
```

Where possible initialize member variables in the initializer list. `Person can be improved as well:

```
    Person(string first, string last, int identification):
        firstName(first),
        lastName(last),
        id(identification)
    {
    }
```

Now the divide by zero bug spotted by Rakete1111's can be found and fixed.

Comment: Still no progress... The program is still crashing

Comment: @Aditya This should work. For what input did the program keeps crashing?

Comment: @Aditya In addition to the empty vector problem @Rakete1111 spotted, all of your IO is unchecked, so there is plenty of room for bad inputs. For example input of "a b c 1 1" puts `cin` into an error state because "c" is not a valid integer. This is not caught, so `Student s` will be created with undefined input. No one can say what will happen then.

Comment: @bkVnet .For this input: Bob Smith 1482342\n 2\n  100 90\n

Comment: Unable to reproduce. input: "Bob Smith 1482342 2 100 90" Output: "Calling
Done
Name: Smith, Bob
ID: 1482342
Grade: O"